# Conversion of datetime to varchar not working when passing through variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I came across this weird problem where I need to convert `datetime` to `varchar`.

I ran these 2 queries:

```
declare @d datetime 
set @d ='31/12/2019 16:12:25.317'

select @d

select convert(varchar(50), '31/12/2019 16:12:25.317', 101)
```

The first query throws an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The second query works fine.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: i always use this format when i need the time: `'2019-12-31T16:12:25.317'`. Should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I guess correct, you are looking for 103 date time format (British/French) which is DD/MM/YYYY. That case you can try this below-

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME
SET @d =CONVERT(DATETIME, '31/12/2019 16:12:25.317',103)

SELECT @d

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '31/12/2019 16:12:25.317', 103)
```

Answer (score 1):

The failure is happening at the first step, because `@d` is declared as a `datetime` rather than a string (unless your internationalization settings allow it).  I think you intend:

```
declare @d varchar(255) 
set @d = '31/12/2019 16:12:25.317';

select convert(date, @d, 103)
```

In general, when setting datetime constants, you should use:

```
declare @d datetime;
set @d = '2019-12-31T16:12:25.317';
```

This is SQL Server's location-independent method of defining a date/time.  Caveat:  Although this is the correct method, I routinely leave out the `T` to be compatible with other databases (and it still works always or almost always).